# Error while uploading: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want upload a file using the chrome console. Thats what I do:

```
document.getElementById('design-upload-open-file-browser-qa').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('design-upload-open-file-browser-qa').children[0].value='path to file';
```

The first line is to activate the input field.
I get the error: VM1929:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
    at :1:9

Here the elements:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't do it. Read the error message 5 times. Then repeat: _which may only be programmatically set..._

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the value of an input of type file for security reasons.

[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)